# Keep lines containing only 3 fields

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, gawk, uniq

I have a .txt file in this format:

```
 USER:EMAIL:PHONE
```

but some lines only have

```
 USER:EMAIL
```

I want to extract only the lines containing 3 fields, example

```
 USER:EMAIL:PHONE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help:

```
awk -F':' 'NF==3{print}{}' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked :) I'll green tick u once time expires haha

Comment: `awk -F: 'NF==3' file` also works, less typing :-)